# How to sort data in descending order and show in table, using functional components in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React project, In that project, data is coming from the Backend, for that data

I need to do the sort. The data are only numbers. I am printing data in a console by using

useEffect Hook. Now I have to write two functions first function is to show data in Ascending

The order and the second function is to show data in Descending order. For this I have to use

Sort method But I don't know how to write this function using state. And I have to apply those

functions to sort Icon.

This is Form.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';
import Aumservice from '../../service/aum-service';


const GetAumListComponent = (props) => {

useEffect(() => {
        (async function () {
            const response = await Aumservice.getAum()
            console.log(response.data.list.map(ele => ele.maxValue))
        })()
    }, [])

 return (
        <div>
            <Aumcompanymodal data={editAumData} editSubmitFunction={editSubmitFunction} openModal={modal} closeModal={handleCancelModal}></Aumcompanymodal>
            <IconContext.Provider
                value={{ size: '25px' }}
            >
                <Table bordered>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>So No</th>
                            <th>Min</th>
                            <th>Max <i class="fas fa-sort fa-2x common"></i></th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {props.getAumState.map((currentValue, index) => {
                            return < tr key={index + 1} >
                                <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                                <td>{currentValue.minValue}</td>
                                <td>{currentValue.maxValue}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <MdEdit onClick={() => editMethod(currentValue)}></MdEdit>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </IconContext.Provider>
        </div >
    )
}

export default GetAumListComponent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume, you have stored your data in state like this:

`const [data, setData] = React.useState([])`

Then you will create these two functions:

```
const sortAscending = () => {
    let sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    setData(sortedData)
}
const sortDescending = () => {
    let sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => b - a)
    setData(sortedData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use useEffcet
function call orderBy -
    orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')

useEffect(() => {
            db.collection('messages').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot(snapshot 
=>     {
                setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
            })
```